# create local fileList from Azure Devops Repos

Tags: azure, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on a script solution to capture status changes of an Azure DevOps repo.

Basically here is what we need:

1. The script is supposed to create a file list that contains ALL files in an Azure repo, and save it to local drive.
2. If the newly generated file list has changes, i.e., a file gets removed/added, the script should create a separate file list that records these changes.

Step 2 I can take care of myself.

But since I am not familiar with the DevOps API, could anyone help me on this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you can fetch repo to local drive, and list files in this directory.

If you could fetch repo to local drive, you can git log -1 for latest change commit.